# Get detailed contents of an item clicked in a listview in next activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, listviewitem

Hi i am working on a code in which in a listview it shows up some details like name and price , which comes from MySQL database . Now when I want to click on that particular item in that listview, what i want is that I want to move in to next activity the layout to which will be the same , only the data keeps changing when an item is clicked.

Like when I click on the Name A , i want to open a new activity in whcih the name as well as its address pincode , phone number will be shown up in details .

I have fetched all the details in the listview and shown up some which i want  there and the next are passed to the detailed activity .
But i am only getting the key  in toast and settext of second activity that is "NameAddressPincodePhone_Number" not the values associated with them  . 
Please look at the code I have written. Please help

Activity with listview

```
public class Plumbers extends Activity {
    String myJSON;

    public static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "Address";
    public static final String TAG_PINCODE = "Pincode";
    public static final String TAG_PHONENUMBER = "Phone_Number";
    public static final String TAG_DOB = "DOB";
    public static final String TAG_AADHARNUMBER = "Aadhar_Number";
    public static final String TAG_Price = "price";
    public static final String TAG_Spl = "spl";

    JSONArray peoples = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;

    ListView list;
    EditText search;
    Spinner spin;

    protected Object adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);
        personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        getData();
    }

    protected void showList(){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

            for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);

                String Name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String price = c.getString(TAG_Price);
                String spl = c.getString(TAG_Spl);

                HashMap<String,String> plumbers = new HashMap<String,String>();
                plumbers.put(TAG_NAME,Name);
                plumbers.put(TAG_Price,price);
                plumbers.put(TAG_Spl,spl);

                personList.add(plumbers);
            }

            final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Plumbers.this, personList, R.layout.plumber,
                    new String[]{TAG_NAME ,TAG_Spl,TAG_Price },
                    new int[]{R.id.Name , R.id.spl ,R.id.price}
            );

            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,  View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    adapter.getItem(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Plumbers.this, Plumber1.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Name", TAG_NAME);
                    intent.putExtra("Address", TAG_ADDRESS);
                    intent.putExtra("Pincode", TAG_PINCODE);
                    intent.putExtra("Phone_Number", TAG_PHONENUMBER);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            spin.setAdapter((SpinnerAdapter) adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getData(){
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new   BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.7/homerun/plumbers.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                myJSON=result;
                showList();
            }
        }

        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();
    }
}
```

Activity for next Details of an item

```
public class Plumber1 extends Activity { 
    ImageView img,call;
    TextView pl1,nm,ad,phn,qu,pin;
    String  Name,Address,Pincode,Phone_Number;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.plumber1);
        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imag);
        call=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.call);
        pl1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pl1);
        nm=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        ad=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Address);
        pin=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Pincode);
        phn=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.phn);
        qu=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.quotation);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {

        Name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
         Address = intent.getStringExtra("Address");
         Pincode = intent.getStringExtra("Pincode");
         Phone_Number = intent.getStringExtra("Phone_Number");
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  Name + "" + Address + "" + Pincode + "" + Phone_Number +"" ,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

        nm.setText(Name+"");
    ad.setText(Address+"");
    pin.setText(Pincode+"");
    phn.setText(Phone_Number+"");
        call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent in = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri
                        .parse("tel:+918058706096"));
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Php file

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
    mysql_select_db("homerun");  
    $sql="select * from plumbers WHERE Status = '1'  GROUP BY price  ORDER BY  name ASC" ;  
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $result = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result,
        array('Name'=>$row[1],'spl'=>$row[8],'price'=>$row[7]));
    }

    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you would at least be getting your TAG_DATA values ...  also in your onItemClickListener you call adapter.getItem(position) but never do anything with its data.

Comment: No i am getting only the key that is in toast and settext i am getting this "NameAddressPincodePhone_Number" that is am getting only the key not the values . Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is wrong**

```
intent.putExtra("Name", TAG_NAME);
```

`putExtra` have two arguments first one is of **key** and second one is of **value**.In your case first one is correct but in value argument again you are sending a **TAG_NAME(which is wrong)**.

**Use below code**

```
intent.putExtra("Name",personList.get(position).get(TAG_NAME));
intent.putExtra("Address",personList.get(position).get(TAG_ADDRESS));
intent.putExtra("Pincode",personList.get(position).get(TAG_PINCODE));


intent.putExtra("Phone_Number",personList.get(position).get(TAG_PHONENUMBER));

startActivity(intent);
```

Just Copy Above Code

**Also Update your for loop to below code**

```
 for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);

                String Name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String price = c.getString(TAG_Price);
                String spl = c.getString(TAG_Spl);
                String Address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                String Pincode = c.getString(TAG_PINCODE);
                String Phone_Number = c.getString(TAG_PHONENUMBER);

                HashMap<String,String> plumbers = new HashMap<String,String>();
                plumbers.put(TAG_NAME,Name);
                plumbers.put(TAG_Price,price);
                plumbers.put(TAG_Spl,spl);
                plumbers.put(TAG_ADDRESS,Address);
                plumbers.put(TAG_PINCODE,Pincode);
                plumbers.put(TAG_PHONENUMBER,Phone_Number);

                personList.add(plumbers);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I did what you asked to do , But now in the second activity i am getting only the name value and other values are null . Is it becausethat In the first activity in listview i have shown only the name , if yes then please help me out as in first i want to show only name not address pincode etc. want to show them in next activity .  

intent.putExtra("Name",personList.get(position).get(TAG_NAME));
intent.putExtra("Address",personList.get(position).get(TAG_ADDRESS));
intent.putExtra("Pincode",personList.get(position).get(TAG_PINCODE));

PLEASE HELP .. THANKS

Comment: I didn't got you sir what you said "copy and below code" . Sir can u please elaborate

Comment: Just tell me what you want to show in Listview and what in other activity.

Comment: I want to show the name , specialisation 'spl' and price in listview which i am getting correctly from json . Now when i click on any item in that listview or any name in that listview i want to move on to the next activity in which the name ,address ,pincode and phone_number must be shown up there of that particular name clicked in that listview . Thnaks for replying sir . Please help sir

Comment: what is the error you are getting by implementing my UPDATED answer?

Comment: I am not getting any error .. WHat i am getting is that when i clicked on that item , I got the name value only and other values were null whether in toast thing or settext , it showed up only the name and all other values address pin ,phone were null . Thanks .. Waiting for your help sir , I am also from jaipur :)

Comment: problem was that you were not adding values of address,pincode,phone_number in `arraylist`. So now **update** your for loop as shown in my answer

Comment: Yes sir got it .. Thanks a lot . Also can you please tell me that how will i get format as Name="Name value" , in my second activity as i am getting Namevalue only , i want Name : XYZ like this . Thanks a lot sir , Thanks for your help and support .

Comment: nm.setText("Name - "+ Name ); Do same for address,pincode,phone_number. In which college are you?

Comment: I am in jecrc sir ... Thnaks a lot for your help